# How do I "re-register" callback jQuery event functions in the refreshed partial view

Tags: jquery

I have a partial view need register several event callback functions for it, however whenever I refreshed the partial to load new data, the elements which have been registered with event callbacks will lost the registration, how should I handle this and if I use jQuery auto refresh function like:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function () { $('#DivId').load(URL); },
        10000
    );
```

which will refresh a partial within DivId, how can I register callbacks then...Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/), this will help you.

Example:

```
$('anySelecror').live('click', function() {
  // Live handler called.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load) function has a callback so you can use that to rebind your handlers:

```
setInterval(
    function() {
        $('#DivId').load(URL, function() {
            /* Rebind your handlers here. */
        });
     },
     10000
);
```

Or you might be able to use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) or [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) instead of putting handlers on elements within `#DivId`.